# При написании php кода для отправки записи в базу данных выходит ошибка

Tags: php, база-данных

Message: trim(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated
Filename: libraries/Form_validation.php
Line Number: 1059
Чем заменить строку : (trim($str) !== '');  раз это устаревший способ?

```php
     * @param   string
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function required($str)
    {
        return is_array($str)
            ? (empty($str) === FALSE)
            : (trim($str) !== '');
    }
```

[image: Ошибки]

Comment: Это не устаревший способ, это вы пытаетесь в trim запихнуть null вместо строки. Ошибка не в показанном вами коде, а где-то в другом месте, где у вас вместо строки оказался null

Comment: Ну или добавьте специальную обработку значения nul в эту функцию required, если вы считаете что null это нормально